# Why is flex layout giving my elements unwanted space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make three divs sit side-by-side with some margin between them but it's making all the elements in the div to be dissaranged.   I attached the code and expected layout below.

Expected Layout.[image]

HTML / CSS code:

```css
.services h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: #da0b0b;
}

.services {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.services-content {
  display: flex;
  /* //justify-content: center;
  //align-items: center; */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.service {
  background-color: #feefef;
  width: 400px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  /* box-sizing: border-box; */
}
```

```html
      <section class="services">
        <h2>Our Services</h2>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="services-content">
          <div class="service">
            <img
              src="./images/SVGs/education.jpg"
              alt="Education Logo"
              srcset=""
            />
            <p>IMMIGRATION THROUGH EDUCATION</p>

            <p>
              We work with all Canadian universities and colleges! Study in
              Canada is the most secure way for immigration to Canada
            </p>

            <a href="#form" class="apply">Apply Here</a>
          </div>

          <div class="service">
            <img
              src="./images/SVGs/business.jpg"
              alt="Business Logo"
              srcset=""
            />

            <p>IMMIGRATION THROUGH BUSINESS</p>

            <p>
              There are lots of immigration programs for business owners. Launch
              your business in Canada!
            </p>

            <a href="#form" class="apply">Apply Here</a>
          </div>

          <div class="service">
            <img
              src="./images/SVGs/employment.jpg"
              alt="Employment Logo"
              srcset=""
            />

            <p>IMMIGRATION THROUGH EMPLOYMENT</p>

            <p>
              There are some application processes that will help you to move to
              Canada permanently through employment streams.
            </p>

            <a href="#form" class="apply">Apply Here</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

I'm trying to use Flexbox, but it's giving the elements in the div a weird layout. I can't seem to get rid of the spacing and I've looked but I can't find code or styles that could be causing the weird alignment of the itens.

Error Layout: [image]

Comment: Your posted code - in the [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/p5ynvo8g/) - generates a layout that looks fairly close to your desired layout; are you sure you've copied enough of your existing code to reproduce the problem? If you look at the differences between the code posted here, and your own code, you may find you've already mostly solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps better to use grid in your services-content

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.services h2 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: #da0b0b;
}

.services {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.services-content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(400px, auto));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.service {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #feefef;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.service a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="services">
  <h2>Our Services</h2>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="services-content">
    <div class="service">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/64/48" alt="Education Logo" srcset="" />
      <p>IMMIGRATION THROUGH EDUCATION</p>
      <p>We work with all Canadian universities and colleges! Study in Canada is the most secure way for immigration to Canada</p>
      <a href="#form" class="apply">Apply Here</a>
    </div>

    <div class="service">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/64/48" alt="Business Logo" srcset="" />
      <p>IMMIGRATION THROUGH BUSINESS</p>
      <p>There are lots of immigration programs for business owners. Launch your business in Canada!</p>
      <a href="#form" class="apply">Apply Here</a>
    </div>

    <div class="service">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/64/48" alt="Employment Logo" srcset="" />
      <p>IMMIGRATION THROUGH EMPLOYMENT</p>
      <p>There are some application processes that will help you to move to Canada permanently through employment streams.</p>
      <a href="#form" class="apply">Apply Here</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```